# Enlarge Start Menu in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I can only pin 14 links to my Start Menu.  When pinning a 15th, it doesn't show in the list.  Is there any way to expand the height of the Start Menu so it shows more items?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Start button, choose Properties. Choose the Start Menu button. Click Customize. Bump up "Number of recent programs to display" to an appropriate number.

Comment: I am not using recent proograms, in fact i have them disabled.  Only permanent pins.

Comment: @foampile try it anysway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right-click the Taskbar
2. Click Properties
3. Got to the Start Menu tab
4. Click Customize
5. Enter a larger number in the `Number of recent programs to display` box

Comment: I am not using recent proograms, in fact i have them disabled.  Only permanent pins.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/)? :)

It's a classic start menu for 7 and 8.